# First Click on Telerik RadGridView activates the RadGridview, but does not select a row

Tags: wpf, xaml, telerik, radgridview

Context: I have a search box above my grid.

When I click from my search box into the grid I want it to select a row. It doesn't. Instead it appears to be setting the focus on the grid. I can click again to select a row. Technically that makes sense, but it's not intuitive for the general user.

Here is the XML for the grid:

> ```
> <telerik:RadGridView Name="poRadGridView" 
>                      Grid.Row="1"
>                      SelectionUnit="FullRow" 
>                      HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
>                      IsReadOnly="True" 
>                      VerticalAlignment="Top" 
>                      ItemsSource="{Binding POs}" 
>                      AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
>                      FontSize="25" 
>                      SelectionMode="Single"
>                      ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I didn't mention is I was using the row selection event to identify when the selected row changed. I'm using MVVM it was recommended that I identify changes in the selected row through data binding rather than event monitoring. So the following was added to the RadGridView definition:

> SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPO, Mode=TwoWay}"

For some reason this works.

Comment: If you are going to vote something down, please leave a comment!